# How to solve higher index roots?

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

I have the equation

> $$r = \sqrt[8]{16}.$$

Very briefly, how do I simplify this and what is the process?

Comment: thank you for the edit @user296602 !

Comment: You mean you want $r = 2^{1/2}$?

Comment: Notice that $16 = 2^4$ and recall that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$. Recall also that taking an $8$-th root is the same as raising to the power $1/8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt[8]{16} = 16^\frac{1}{8} = 2^{4 \cdot \frac{1}{8}} = 2^\frac{1}{2} = \sqrt 2$$

Comment: thank you! will mark correct in 7 minutes :D